# Coordinates of Solution in Particle Swarm Cryptanalysis

Tags: c#, optimization, particle-swarm

I am writing a C# application that will solve a Monoalphabetic Substitution Ciphers using a Particle Swarm Algorithm.

Essentially I understand the process and have found all the algorithms I need to update the vector ect. What I can't work out is how to calculate a 26 character solution's position/cooridnates in the problem space so I can use it in the algorithm found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42258/Particle-swarm-optimization-for-function-optimizat

Is the position simply an array of ints relating to the characters position in the alphabet?

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You're doing..a..what..i...*head blown*

Comment: That would better be reflected by a permutation than a position. But anyway, this will hardly work because cryptanalysis problems make bad fitness functions. More advanced cryptography will give you problems where you're either correct or wrong and there's only one way to be correct. So you have absolutely no "gradient". You're doing random search.

Comment: @Andreas: good point.

But in the case of substitution cypher (a simple cypher case), you might define the fitness function based on "how much the uncyphered message make sense?" which could be based on "recognized words (as soon as a sufficient number of letter substitutions are correctly guessed) or proximity to plain English (or any target language using n-gram statistics for instance).

Answer (score 2):

PSO basically works in continuous space. Of course, there are versions for discrete problems, and it seems that this problem is discrete.

You have defined a space. Make it continuous with bounds (0, 26).
Now one can use a particle position as a mean of a statistical distribution, or just get the floor of the value.
It would be great if you had some memoization because there will be many duplicated calls.

The next thing are constraints. No letter can be substituted to the same one.
You can solve it in multiple ways, the simplest again would be a repair function:
if your algorithm encounters a value that has been set already (because multiple values have the same floor), leave it and come back later when you figure out what letters are still available.

BTW, you can also use PSO to train an ANN that solves the problem using statistics of letter occurrences in a language.

Hope that helps. Cheers!